# Copy and paste for a specific number of times

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column of data (F) and a column of numbers (G), and I want to copy each row of column F and paste to column H for a number of times, which depends on the corresponding value in column G.
How could I do it using vba?

```
  For exemple:      
          F          G        H
  4     Q7-CA        1      Q7-CA
  5     Q5-CA        2      Q5-CA
  6     A1-CA        1      Q5-CA
  7     Q6-CA        4      A1-CA
  8  BULK-TACEHU     1      Q6-CA
  9    AMA-EG        2      Q6-CA
 10                         Q6-CA
 11                         Q6-CA
 12                       BULK-TACEHU
 13                         AMA-EG
 14                         AMA-EG
```

Comment: [Related.](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/1873/flow-control-structures/8169/for-loop#t=201609051722164893186)  [Also related.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-macro-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b)

Comment: Still don't know how to do it.......

Comment: Loop through all your rows (i). For each row, get G number (k). Loop again k times copying F in H. Next i.

Comment: @TonyY try the code in my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code below, I used row 1 as the row where the data starts (modify according to your needs) :

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyNumofTimes()

Dim LastRow     As Long
Dim Sht         As Worksheet
Dim lRow        As Long
Dim newRow      As Long
Dim CopyRep     As Integer
Dim cpyRow      As Integer

' modify Sheet1 to your Sheet name
Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

' modify 1 form the line number you are starting your data
newRow = 1

With Sht
    ' find last row with data in Column F
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

    For lRow = 1 To LastRow
        CopyRep = .Cells(lRow, "G").Value

        ' make sure you have a number of at least 1 in Column G
        If CopyRep > 0 Then
            For cpyRow = 1 To CopyRep
                .Cells(newRow, "H") = .Cells(lRow, "F")
                newRow = newRow + 1
            Next cpyRow
        End If

    Next lRow

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly. I really appreciate your help !!  What is the function of "option explicit" ?