# Copy and Paste nth times using Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way for a script to recognize a number and automate a copy and paste loop using that number?

E.g:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Have tried to search around though results have returned the copy and pasting of number of rows/columns or as shown in this link:

[Copy and paste for a specific number of times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39335204/copy-and-paste-for-a-specific-number-of-times)
the results are for Excel and not Sheets.

Please find [Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tnJI0pffQBkd8nqIlBtFaMTJAgvMT7IMWHdeSflI6CM/edit?usp=sharing)

Thank you

Comment: The problem with what you are saying is that when you check the checkbox the selected range changes.  You could do this with a custom modeless dialog.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details.

Comment: @Cooper So what if the selected range changes? Can't we simply offset the range to get `C1`?

Comment: I was assuming that you wanted to copy the active range but I guess that may not be true.  Anyway you probably can figure what you want from what I provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy Paste N Times:

I guess you are having trouble getting it to run.   First you need to run launchMyDialog() and before you do that you will have to change the html file name.  And then when the dialog comes up you need to select the range.  You can do that before or after  you run the dialog because it's a modeless dialog.  Once you have the range selected click on the upper button and once the dialog is all filled in down to number of repeats then push the copy and it does the copy.  Just like the animation.

gs:

```
function copyNTimes(obj) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const {rg,roff,coff,repeat} = obj.parameters;
  const vs = sh.getRange(rg).getDisplayValues();
  console.log('rg: %s,roff: %s,coff: %s,repeat: %s',rg,roff,coff,repeat);
  [...Array.from({length:repeat})].forEach((_,i) => {
    sh.getRange(rg).offset(roff * (i + 1), coff * (i + 1),vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs)
  })
}

function launchMyDialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("ah1").setWidth(600),"Repeat Copy");
}

function selectRange() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rgA1 = sh.getActiveRange().getA1Notation();
  return rgA1;
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <style>
  input {margin: 2px 5px 2px 0; }
  input::placeholder {placeholder:font-size:6px;opacity:0.5}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="form1">
    <input type="text" name="roff" placeholder="Row Offset from upper Left" size="35" />
    <br /><input type="text" name="coff" placeholder="Column Offset From upper left"  size="35"/>
    <br /><input type="text" id="rg" name="rg" placeholder="Select Range and hit button" size="35" />
    <input type="button" value="Select Range" onClick="selectRange();"  size="35"/>
    <br /><input type="text" name="repeat" placeholder="Enter number of times to repeat" size="35"/>
    <br /><input type="button" value="Copy" onclick="sendData(this.parentNode);" />
  </form>
  <script>
    function sendData() {
        let form = document.getElementById("form1");
        let obj = {parameters:[ ...form].reduce((a,c)=> (a[c.name] = c.value, a),{})};
        console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler( () => {
          let f = [...document.getElementById("form1")];
          f.forEach((c,i) => {if(c.type == "text"){c.value = ''}})})
        .copyNTimes(obj);

      }
      function selectRange() {
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler((r)=> {
          document.getElementById("rg").value=r;
        })
        .selectRange();
      }
      console.log("Code");
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @Cooper, thank you for your answer and screen rec of result. However, I'm unable to get the same result as you. Have pasted the GS script and recieve ***TypeError: Cannot read property 'parameters' of undefined
copyNTimes @ Untitled.gs:4*** Could I ask for any suggestions on this.

Comment: Please discard my most recent comment. Took a look into [Creating HTML Files](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/)  Thank you again.

Comment: What am I supposed to learn there?